# Making parameter Optional with multivalue parameter in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter in which I have selected "Allow Multiple Values" at the same time how can i make the same parameter as optional. For example if customer wants to leave the parameter value as blank he can on the other hand if customer wants to select any value then it is allowed. In Case any of the parameter is left blank the code should run

I am using below mentioned query where i want to make enrollment_type the parameter where i want above mentioned conditions

```
Where (School IN (@school)) 
  AND (School_Year IN (@schoolyear)) 
  AND ((EnrollmentType IN (@EnrollmentType)) OR ('' IN (@EnrollmentType))) 
   OR (Grade IN (@Grade))
```

Comment: You cannot set a parameter to Allow multiple values and at the same time allow null values. How are you populating your parameters?

Answer (score 1):

you could in ssrs >> parameter properties on general tab select option for allow blank values is sql you need :

```
Where (School IN (@school) or @school='' )
```

you can also do the same thing with allow null values

```
Where (School IN (@school) or @school is null )
```

Comment: After i add "Where (School IN (@school) or @school='' )" and select "allow blank values" it is again not allowing to select the check box(blank)

Comment: Now it is working,  please ignore from last comment, Thank you.

Comment: Have a question,
If do as per your suggestion. it works when i add "specify values" manually  in Available Value(in report parameter) and do the same with default values. it works fine
But when i select dataset value in specify values and blank in default values , it is not working
Any suggestion please

Comment: your dataset values need to have that default value in it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to make your `enrollment_type` parameter as optional to the users. If you are looking to make no filter on enrollment_type by default, you can set the default setting of the parameter.

If you are populating your parameter value from query, set the default value exactly same as available values i.e. `parameter>Default Values>Get Value from Query>Dataset>Value`

By setting both the available values and default values same. You will not be asked to select any value for enrollment_type and the `Select All` option will be automatically checked.

You need to add `EnrollmentType IN (@EnrollmentType)` in your dataset.